# In Germany, is it possible to get an EU long-term residency (Daueraufenthalt–EU) in 21 months with an EU Blue Card and B1-level German?

Tags: germany, eu, blue-card, residency

In Germany, if you have an EU Blue card, you can get a permanent settlement permit in just 21 months if you also have B1-level knowledge of the German language. (Source: https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326556/en/) However, there's another kind of permanent residency you can get in Germany: the EU long-term residency, or Daueraufenthalt–EU. Normally, this residency takes 5 years to acquire, but it's not clear to me whether this period could also be shortened to 21 months with an EU Blue card and sufficient language skills. Could someone clarify?

Comment: [§9b - EU long-term residence permit](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0143) is based on [Directive 2003/109/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32003L0109) which doesn't forsee a shorten period.

Answer (score 1):

You can now get a "usual" permanent settlement permit (after 21 months) and after 5 years apply for Daueraufenthalt–EU **in addition** to it (you will keep your current permanent settlement permit and get 2nd one, which will be Daueraufenthalt–EU).